# Want to make optional for time part in php input

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below input type code in php:-

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="trx_date_time_1" class="form-control" id="trx_date_time_1">
```

Here input type is `datetime-local`, where i can give both `date and time`.

**What i want:-**

I want to keep time part optional .

**Problem i am facing:-**

if i give only date as input it's saying invalid format.

If i don't give any input then it's taking as blank. it's ok.

**I just want to make time part optional, date should be compulsory.**

Can anyone suggest??

Comment: I think you need to use two separate inputs, one for the date and one for the time. Then you can make the time input optional.

Comment: 1. make `date` and `time` two column in table where `time` can accept null. 2. use `varchar` type field and through coding check `date` and `time`,if both come then concatenate them  otherwise directly save them.1 option is much better

Comment: Why optional? Why not default to current time, say, if left blank?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two separate columns in you database table. This is an error of database field.
Make `date` as `DATE` type column field and `time` as `TIME` type column field. I am give you an example of SQL as per one of my sample database table. Change those fields as per yours.

```
ALTER TABLE `loginsignup` ADD `date` DATE NOT NULL AFTER `Password`, ADD `time` TIME NULL AFTER `date`;
```

Save those value separately. Then only your problem can be removed.